# react-hook-form resolver type error using Yup

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm creating an auth form and I'm referencing the react-hook-form [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) on how to use yup to validate my inputs. As far as I can tell, everything is pretty much identical to the implementation provided in the docs. However, I'm getting the error on the `useForm` resolver (show below). Any idea where I'm going wrong?

- `"react-hook-form": "^7.15.2"`
- `"yup": "^0.32.9"`
- `"@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.1"`

##### error

[image]

##### code

```js
interface IFormInputs {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirm: string;
}

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
  passwordConfirm: yup.string().required(),
});

const SignUp = (): JSX.Element => {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormInputs>({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInputs> = () => {
    const values = getValues();
    console.log('values', values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledPaper>
        <StyledTypography>Sign Up</StyledTypography>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Controller
            name="email"
            rules={{ required: 'this field is required' }}
            defaultValue=""
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                fullWidth
                label="Email"
                variant="filled"
                value={field.value}
                error={!!errors.email}
                helperText="Provide an email"
                {...field}
              />
            )}
          />
          <StyledButton type="submit">Submit</StyledButton>
        </form>
      </StyledPaper>
      <div>
        <StyledTypography>Already have an account? Log in.</StyledTypography>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a library bug, downgrade **@hookform/resolvers** to `2.8.0` seems to fix the issue.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**Edit:** You can remove the error on version `2.8.1` by forcing `yubResolver` to use the `yub.AnyObjectSchema` generic. Thanks to 
[Mihai-github](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/issues/234#issuecomment-922933589) for figuring that out.

```
useForm<IFormInputs>({
  resolver: yupResolver<yup.AnyObjectSchema>(schema),
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: `Attempted import error: 'AnyObjectSchema' is not exported from 'yup' (imported as 'yup')` this error is showing, what to do? @Nearhuscarl

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi what yup/resolver versions are you using?

Comment: @hookform/resolvers@2.8.4
yup@0.32.11
react-hook-form@7.20.5 it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
useForm<IFormInputs>({
  resolver: yupResolver<IFormInputs>(schema),
});
```

No need to add any `Yup Schema type`, simply pass `useForm<interface/type>` to `yupResolver<interface/type>`.

Note. Make sure the schema should contain the same keys as `interface/type`

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can fix them like this: `resolver: yupResolver<yup.AnyObject>(schema),`

Comment: Does not work for me. Nor does `resolver: yupResolver<yup.AnyObjectSchema>(schema)`

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above work for me. And I don't want to downgrade `@hookform/resolvers` to a 2+ year version as said by NearHuscarl. The work around is to silence the error by adding `// @ts-expect-error ts(2322)` on the line before the error occurs. In your case, before the line
`resolver: yupResolver(schema),`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by upgrading to the latest versions of each libs:

```
"@hookform/resolvers": "3.3.1",
"react-hook-form": "7.51.2",
"yup": "1.4.0"
```

also, if you had `@types/yup` installed, you should remove it as yup now exposes its own types and may interfere with the lib's types.

Edit : note, as from a recent [Github post](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/issues/648#issuecomment-2002471891) there seems to be an issue with @hookform/resolvers after version 3.3.1

Note that I'm on typescript 5.3.3