# Index signature for type 'string' is missing error when assigning Yup Resolver

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm using material ui with react-hook-form and yup to create and validate forms.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Container, FormControl, FormHelperText, InputLabel, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { typography } from '@mui/system';
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from "yup";

interface IFormData {
  srcAddress:string,
  tgtAddress:string
}


const onSubmitHandler : SubmitHandler<IFormData> = (data:IFormData)=> {
  console.log(data);
} 

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  srcAddress: yup.string().required(),
  tgtAddress: yup.string().required()
});

function App() {
  const {register, handleSubmit, watch, formState} = useForm<IFormData>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
        <Stack
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
          minHeight="100vh"
          minWidth="100vw"
          sx={{
            '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width:"30%"},
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="h4" sx={{textAlign:"center"}} display="inline">Money sender</Typography>
          <TextField size="small" label="Source Address"  id="srcAddress" variant="standard"  {...register('srcAddress')} />
          <TextField size="small" label="Target Address"  variant="standard"  {...register('tgtAddress')} />
          <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Send</Button>
        </Stack>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> {     "resource":
> "/Users/.../Documents/Development/react/send-receive-money/src/App.tsx",
> "owner": "typescript",  "code": "2322",     "severity": 8,  "message":
> "Type '(values: unknown, context: object | undefined, options:
> ResolverOptions<AssertsShape<Assign<ObjectShape, { srcAddress:
> RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, Record<string, any>>;
> tgtAddress: RequiredStringSchema<...>; }>>>) => Promise<...>' is not
> assignable to type 'Resolver<IFormData, object>'.\n  Types of
> parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.\n    Type
> 'ResolverOptions' is not assignable to type
> 'ResolverOptions<AssertsShape<Assign<ObjectShape, { srcAddress:
> RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, Record<string, any>>;
> tgtAddress: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, Record<...>>;
> }>>>'.\n      Type 'IFormData' is not assignable to type
> 'AssertsShape<Assign<ObjectShape, { srcAddress:
> RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, Record<string, any>>;
> tgtAddress: RequiredStringSchema<string | undefined, Record<...>>;
> }>>'.\n        Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type
> 'IFormData'.",    "source": "ts",     "startLineNumber": 31,
> "startColumn": 5,   "endLineNumber": 31,    "endColumn": 13 }

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "send-receive-money",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.15.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "web3": "^1.5.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Have been playing around a bit trying to solve it without success.

Comment: Can you add your package.json to the question?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Just taking a shot in the dark. Can you follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277986/9449426) answer and see if it works for you? There is something wrong with the yup resolver library lately.

Comment: Yikes! I was browsing the github issues and did find nothing. thanks!