# React Hook Form - Typescript issues and error handling?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am currently switching over to React Hook Form from Formik. I am also using Material UI V5 and yup for validation.

I've got two problems I'm trying to solve at the moment:

1. TS Errors are popping up for various RHF props and options.
2. I'd like to be able to validate both onBlur and onSubmit, but the HTML5 validation displays onSubmit currently.

Here's my code:

```jsx
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  CircularProgress,
  Grid,
  InputAdornment,
  TextField,
  Theme,
  Typography,
  useMediaQuery,
} from '@mui/material';
import { validationSchema } from './validationSchema'

const LoginForm: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: 'onBlur',
    reValidateMode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: { // <-- TS Error: Type '{ email: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: undefined; email?: string | undefined; password?: string | undefined; }'.
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
  });

  const handleSignin = async (credentials: Values) => {
    const { error } = await signIn(Provider.Email, credentials);

    if (error) {
      setLoadingLogin(false);
      setLoginError(true);
    } else {
      router.push('/');
    }
  };

  return (
    <BoxContainer>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSignin)}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Controller
              name="email" // <-- TS Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <TextField
                  {...field}
                  error={!!errors?.email}
                  helperText={errors?.email?.message} // <-- TS Error: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'never'.
                  size="small"
                  autoFocus
                  label="Email"
                  fullWidth
                  autoComplete="email"
                  type="email"
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <EmailIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Controller
              name="password" // <-- TS Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
              error={!!errors?.password}
              helperText={errors?.password?.message} // <-- TS Error: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'never'.
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <TextField
                  {...field}
                  size="small"
                  autoComplete="password"
                  label="Password"
                  fullWidth
                  type="password"
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <LockIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          {loginError && (
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Alert severity="error">
                There was an error logging in.
                <br /> Please try again.
              </Alert>
            </Grid>
          )}
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              // disabled={isSubmitting || loadingLogin}
              disableElevation
              disableRipple
              fullWidth
              size="large"
              type="submit"
              variant="contained">
              Signin
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography
              variant="body2"
              color="textSecondary"
              className="text-center">
              Don't have an account?{' '}
              <Link href="/register">
                <a>Signup</a>
              </Link>
            </Typography>
            {!isDesktop && (
              <Box marginTop={2}>
                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  color="textSecondary"
                  className="text-center">
                  <Link href="/forgot-password">
                    <a>Forgot your password?</a>
                  </Link>
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            )}
            <Box mt={2} className="text-center">
              <Typography
                variant="subtitle2"
                color="textSecondary"
                className="mt-4">
                By continuing to use GearCloset, you agree to our{' '}
                <Link href="/terms-and-conditions">
                  <a>Terms and Conditions.</a>
                </Link>
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </BoxContainer>
  );
}
```

I have commented next to the pieces of code return TS errors.

The second issue is that when I enter an invalid or blank email and then tab, the error state for the input works correctly, however when I press the submit button the email input displays the normal HTML5 validation warning. I'd like for the mode to somehow be both onBlur and onSubmit.

At this point, it seems like RHF *works*, I'm just cleaning up the errors and functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first issue could be linked to this open Github [issue](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/issues/245). There is a workaround, check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277986/2015452).

For the second one you have to set `noValidate` attribute on the `<form />` element and let RHF completely handle the validation.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSignin)} noValidate>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I went ahead and downgraded the resolvers library to 2.8.0 and added the `noValidate` prop to the form, and this appears to have fixed everything. Thanks a ton!